# How to change the directory where PDFs are saved?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am developing an application to split PDFs and mining the internet I managed to do it, however, I would like to change the folder where the PDFs are saved. Can you help me?

Here is the code below:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import messagebox


inputpdf = PdfFileReader(askopenfilename(), "rb")
print(inputpdf)

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
print("PDF Dividido com sucesso.")
messagebox.showinfo("System Message", "PDF successfully divided.")
```

Comment: How do you currently get to the current folder where the pdf currently exists? How about changing that?

Comment: 12944qwerty hi, with ```askopenfile()```

Comment: What does `inputpdf` print?

Comment: ```<PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader object at 0x00000207E7F355E0>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do open("document-page.pdf") you can insert a pathname where document-page.pdf is. For example ~/Documents/Some_random_folder/new_file.pdf